# Openstack Neutron - error creating network - DBError Constraint Failed

Tags: openstack-neutron

I'm having an issue trying to create a network in Openstack Newton, tried with horizon and with the cli and both fail.

```
> openstack network create --project admin --provider-network-type local --provider-physical-network default --provider-segment 1 --transparent-vlan network0
> HttpException: Internal Server Error
```

This is neutron log:
https://gist.github.com/estebangarcia/8a74834ea05291cdbc9ede40bbd833ff

I've check the database and CONSTRAINT_3 is this one:

> CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_3` CHECK (`vlan_transparent` in (0,1))

This is my neutron.conf: https://gist.github.com/estebangarcia/0c6ce6979e2c2bb45a1bddfd69a3117f

Anybody encountered the same issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody bumps into the same issue. Don't think this is the best solution as I think the constraints are there for some reason. But to skip this issue I've just deleted all the constraints I had issues with from the database.